# Copying a ColdFusion cfparam array into a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, tablesorter

I've have a CF page who's inventory search *form*, `frm_inv` post's back to itself. `frm_inv`'s main *table* of records, `tbl_inv`, uses a `tablesorter`. A *hidden input* (`sort_list`) is used in conjunction with a *cfparam* to keep track of `tbl_inv`'s `sortList`:

**main.cfm**

```
<cfparam name="form.sort_list" type="string" default="1,0">

<form id="frm_inv" action="main.cfm" method="post">
    <input name="sort_list" type="hidden" value="#form.sort_list#"/>
    <table id="tbl_inv" class="tablesorter">
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

When `frm_inv` is submitted, CF uses `sort_list` in `$(document).ready()` to restore `tbl_inv`'s sort order:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sort_list_str = <cfoutput>"#form.sort_list#"</cfoutput>;
    var sort_list = sort_list_str.split(",");

    $("#tbl_inv").tablesorter({
        textExtraction: ['complex'],        
        sortList:[[sort_list[0],sort_list[1]]]
    }).bind("sortEnd", function(sorter) {           
        var sl = sorter.target.config.sortList;
        $("input[name='sort_list']").val(sl.toString());
    });
});
```

**I would rather use arrays than convert a comma separated string into an array like I'm currently doing**

```
<cfparam name="form.sort_list" type="string" default="1,0">
to
<cfparam name="form.sort_list" type="array" default="ArrayNew(2)">
```

**however I need to know the proper javascript and coldfusion syntax in order pose everything that's relevant in arrays exclusively.**

Comment: What have you tried? Also remember that CF is serverside, Meaning you have to pass a value into the HTML/JS so that it can read it. Please edit your post with more details in the example and what code you have tried.

Comment: Indeed it is. My code currently runs ok, I just want my `cfparam` to be an array instead of a string, which may also require the `hidden input` to change, or the use of it (I'm not really sure). Thanks - post updated, pls see new cfparam statement of type="array".

Comment: *My code currently runs ok* So what is the issue? :) ie What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Use `listToArray(form.sort_list, ",")` to convert the submitted field to an array serverside. Do this after declaring it using `cfparam`. But honestly, it is easier to work with a list rather than building an array notation for Javascript. Why not stick with what you already have?

Comment: Did you try `ToScript(cfvar, javascriptvar)`?

Comment: @Alex I had a fundamental misconception of how http transferred data, which is in strings/unicode/ascii/text apparently. I'm ok with parsing the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Copying a ColdFusion ... array into a JavaScript array

Why? For the most part, HTTP only transmits strings, so there is no translation between client and server complex types. Unless you are doing something more than just passing the sort value back and forth, converting between client and server side arrays is just an unnecessary complication. It is simpler to leave the value as a string and do any splitting or parsing on the client side.

You did not really explain what problem you are trying to solve, but .. there is nothing inherently wrong with the current approach. However, it could be simplified a bit. **There is no need to cfoutput the variable again here:**

> **(A)** `var sort_list_str = <cfoutput>"#form.sort_list#"</cfoutput>;`

Since you already stored the current `form.sort_list` value in a hidden form field, the above is redundant. Instead, just read the field's value with javascript ie

**(B)** `var sort_list_str = $("input[name='sort_list']").val();`

Having said that, if you really prefer to work with arrays, you could store a JSON string representation of the arrays instead. Then use parse() and stringify() to convert the arrays back and forth.  Same net effect as your current method, but a bit simpler in terms of code.

**Form:**

```
<cfparam name="form.sort_list" default="[[1,0]]">
...
<input id="sort_list" name="sort_list" 
     type="hidden" value="#encodeForHTML(form.sort_list)#" />
...
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tbl_inv").tablesorter({
        textExtraction: ['complex'],        
        sortList: JSON.parse($("#sort_list").val())
    }).bind("sortEnd", function(sorter) {           
        var sort_arr = sorter.target.config.sortList;
        $("#sort_list").val(JSON.stringify(sort_arr));
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution actually solves the next problem I was going to face with string parsing. Since the `tablesorter` can nest sort's (by ctrl-clicking), the `sortlist` can grow to size N array's (ie, `[[1,0],[2,1],...[N,d]]` where d: sort direction). So hooray again, too bad I can't x2 the your help points.

Comment: ... that's not to say I'm scared of a little parsing (I actually like it - mail me at parselee@yahoo.com lol). Nothing wrong with whipping up a finite state automaton (I think a Pushdown Automata is needed for parsing, which if I remember recognize context-free/nested grammars), except then time investment.

Comment: I figured to use **(A)** based on the flow of the form from browser, to server, and back to browser again. After some thought I realized that **(B)** assumes that the server hasn't modified the *sort_list* input, correct? If so, is this a safe assumption (what if for example the server used the input to stash a status code based on the input's value or something)?

Comment: (Edit) Presumably A and B do the exact same thing. ie Set the *initial* sort order based on the submitted `form.sort_list` value. They both use the same value, so I am not sure I follow where status code fits it into it.

Comment: I'm trying to determine which is a better coding practice in the general case. Why assume that on the "post-back"/"reload" of the submitted form that it's values are still valid? Isn't possible that the value could be reset (by a browser for example).

Comment: Well, that is a different question altogether but I imagine it depends on exactly what the values are used for and how critical it is if they are changed or tampered with. Values only used for client side sorting would likely be less critical.

Comment: Ok then I will stick with the <cfoutput> option for now to be safe.

Comment: It has been a busy day, so perhaps I am completely misunderstanding you, but .. I do not think we are talking about the same thing ;-) Accepting the usual vagaries of client-side-anything, why do you think one is safer than the other? There is not much difference between creating a JS variable and storing/reading the value of the hidden field.  *Both* methods use cfoutput.

Answer (score 4):

For creating a JavaScript variable from a ColdFusion variable, you can use **[`toScript()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/toscript.html)** function.

```
var #toScript(ListToArray(form.sort_list), "sort_list")#;
```

This can be used for wide range of variable types such as strings, arrays, structures etc.

Comment: True, but why involve CF here at all? Since the value is not being used by CF, just leave it as a string, and do the conversions on the client side. Then neither the `cfoutput` OR `toScript` is needed.

Comment: @Leigh Just trying to suggest a coldfusion solution. Even though this is not really necessary here, may be this'll help somewhere.

Comment: Understood. Though technically it works, just pointing out to the asker there is no need to involve CF in the equation in this case. Simpler to just pass along the strings and do the to/from conversions on the client side.

Answer (score -1):

Needs specific syntax to use an array in cfparam: [ColdFusion CFParam Can Use Struct And Array Notation](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/802-coldfusion-cfparam-can-use-struct-and-array-notation.htm)

`<cfparam name="form.sort_list" type="array" default="#ArrayNew( 2 )#">`

Comment: Unlike with simple strings, there is not direct conversion of complex objects. There is still the issue of translating between client and server types. That said, @SamusArin I am curious what is wrong with the current approach.  ie What problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: @Leigh I already solved the problem using string types (which was restoring the tablesorter's sort-list). I totally brain-flatulated when posting this, looking over the server/client side's and how HTTP is transferred as text. I guess my android day's using JSON to transmit datatypes set me up for this failure. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `ArrayNew( x )` throws an exception. I tried that already, is there any other  javascript syntax for declaring an array?

Comment: (Edit - typo) That is a CF function, not javascript. Not sure why you don't just use the JSON method. The server side values are basically being returned to the client the same way, so neither method is any less "safe" than the other.